# Process Start How To Executable under Apps , Not in Background Process

Tags: c#, .net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwZtq.jpg)
I setting my WorkerService appsettings.json like below

```
"AppRun": {
    "App1": {
      "AppName": "CheckDataForm",
      "AppPath": "D:\\2021-Project\\Project\\CheckDataForm-MSSQL\\CheckDataForm\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0-windows\\CheckDataForm.exe"
    },
    "App2": {
      "AppName": "notepad++",
      "AppPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
    },
```

and call the app like this:

```
      //i is foreach count
               
         var AppName = _config["AppRun:App"+i+":AppName"];
         var AppPath = _config["AppRun:App" + i + ":AppPath"];

         //check file exist
         var fileExist = System.IO.File.Exists(AppPath);
      
        if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty (AppName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(AppPath) && 
            fileExist )
        {
            //find APP
            var processApp = Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName);

            //can't find app
            if (processApp.Length <=0 )
            {
                try
                {
                        Process proc = new Process();
                        proc.StartInfo.FileName = AppPath;
                        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = 
                        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppPath);
                        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = 
                        ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

                        proc.Start();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var error = ex;
                }



            }

        }
```

the Process can Start notepad++ And CheckDataForm , but notepad++ And CheckDataForm AP run in **[Background processes]**  , I need AP Run in **[Apps]**
How To  Executable under Apps , Not in  Background Process
, like image show

Comment: Rewrite the question in proper English please - it is barely readable.

Comment: how are you starting your code? is it self a background service?

Comment: yes, it run as service ,
sc.exe create "APPWorkerService" binpath="D:\Project\APPWorkerService\bin\release\net5.0\APPWorkerService.exe"

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the program using the CMD:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppPath);
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C "+AppPath;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
proc.Start();
```

That way will be ran as if you run it as the logged user.

Since you are using a Service, you could use a predefined TASK from the Task Scheduler to run the program:

```
   var ts = new TaskService();
   var task = ts.FindTask("mainTVMTask2");
   task.Run();
```

The nugget package used was:

```
TaskScheduler by David Hall
```

This last code is being used right now to keep an app running, the service is checking if the process is in the process list, if its not, will run that task, previusly created in the Task Scheduler.

[image: This is the Task Im using to run the program from the service]

You might choose the user that will be logged in order to run the process instead of the service that will run with System Account.

The action is a standard run command to start the program that you need.

Comment: hi  , thank you for help  , 

my app is a background service , it will call other app , define in appsettings.json,

i try  the code and it doesn't work

Comment: i try the code , proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C   " +  @""""+ AppPath +  "\"";
the app run in  [Background processes]  too

Comment: i get the TaskScheduler  from github, but it can't run, the task always null  :
   var ts = new TaskService();
   var task = ts.FindTask("myAppName");
   task.Run();

then i use           
// Run a program every day on the local machine
TaskService.Instance.AddTask(ProcName, QuickTriggerType., System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppPath), "");

but app never run , and I need check the is app exist by minute ,

#
 in .net the background service  can't start app at [apps] , just only start app in  [Background processes] , i don't understand ?

  thank you

Comment: // Run a program every day on the local machine
TaskService.Instance.AddTask(ProcName, QuickTriggerType., System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppPath), "").Run();

it still run my app in  [Background processes] , not in [apps]  @@
and notepad++ run, my winform app not start

Comment: Did you create the "myAppName" in the Task Scheduler in Windows?
(Run -> taskschd.msc)

Comment: i didn't, I wrote .net 5 workservice app  to check and call other apps,
workservice every minute to check if other apps not run , workservice  will start it ,
do not execute if it exists

Comment: I check Task Scheduler in Windows ,  other apps like notepad++ already create by  workservice @@

Comment: the task has value , 
but other apps still run at [Background processes]  ,anything i miss? # //proc.Start(); var ts = new TaskService(); var task = ts.FindTask(ProcName); task.Run();

Comment: You might be missing the User account that need to run the task. Make sure that is the logged user that will impersonate the execution of the task.

Comment: yes, I has reCeate TaskScheduler by logged user  , not workserver create System  account

Comment: have you try to run manually the task and make sure it run in the correct scope?

Comment: I  try to run manually from  the  task  , notepad++ and my winform app always run at [Background processes]  ,  @@?

Comment: You might need to check the account that "is running" the Task, or the task itself. There must be a missconfiguration in the task that is preventing to run as a "normal".